# Why is the logf function missing from libc.math?

Tags: cython

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cimport libc.math
cpdef float main():
    cdef float v0
    v0 = 10.000000
    return libc.math.logf(v0)
                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

cython_experiments\test3\testm.pyx:5:20: cimported module has no attribute 'logf'
```

It should be in [the module](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libc/math.pxd#L133), but for some reason it seems to be missing on my system. Where is it?

The regular `libc.math.log` function is there though.

I am using the Cython 0.29.21 from the Anaconda distro on Windows 10.

Comment: It looks like the C99 math functions only went into the upcoming Cython 3 branch (try switching the git branch to 0.29.x to compare). There's nothing magic about the libc includes (they're only provided for convenience) so you can create your own pxd file containing the stuff you need (just copy it)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for pointing it out. I think I'll just wait until the newer version gets released. It is not urgent.